# SQL query selecting from two tables returning duplicate rows

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to run this SQL query:

```
SELECT t.*, tu.*, t.contact_name as contact_name, 
t.contact_email as contact_email, t.ticketnumber as ticketnumber, 
t.subject as subject 
FROM tickets t, ticket_updates tu 
WHERE t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber 
AND tu.type = 'update' AND tu.customer <> 'Y' 
AND t.status = 'Awaiting Customer' AND tu.datetime <= '2014-10-18 16:26:00' 
order by tu.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

It is returning the correct results, but its showing multiple of the same row

Comment: It seams the relation between tickets and ticket_updates is a master detail so if you are getting same identical results, you may have identical rows in child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tu.*...
```

OR you can try a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT t.*, tu.*, t.contact_name as contact_name, t.contact_email as contact_email, 
 t.ticketnumber as ticketnumber, t.subject as subject 
  FROM tickets t, ticket_updates tu 
  WHERE t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber AND 
  tu.type = 'update' AND tu.customer <> 'Y' AND 
  t.status = 'Awaiting Customer' AND 
   tu.datetime <= '2014-10-18 16:26:00' 
   GROUP BY tu.`id`
   order by tu.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Using DISTINCT still returns the same

Comment: there are multiple rows in the ticket_updates table for each row in the tickets table

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix you could use `SELECT DISTINCT`.
Usually, though, duplication is a hint there is a problem with your database and/or join conditions. So make sure there are no duplicates in the tables, and the join conditions are correct.